# I am missing something

Tags: javascript, codepen

I've looked this code over and over.. I typed it as I was learning from lesson  material, and have checked and checked over and over again. the code works for the instructor, but not me. Is it my mistake or is it a problem for the platform I am using? It not working may seems trivial comparing to needing to understand what is being taught, but I still would like to understand all that I can. thank you.  https://codepen.io/Slimmwillis/pen/EQWpGP?editors=1111

```
function yearsUntilRetirement(name, year) {
  var age = calculateAge(year);
  var retirement = 65 - age;
  if (retirement >= 0) {
    console.log(name + ' retires in ' + retirement + ' years.');
  } else {
    console.log(name + ' is already retired.');
  }
}
yearsUntilRetirment('John', 1990);
```

Comment: Maybe it's not working because you're attempting to call `yearsUntilRetirment` instead of `yearsUntilRetirement`. Your console should have pointed this out with a message like _"Uncaught ReferenceError: yearsUntilRetirment is not defined"_

Comment: You're missing an acceptable title for this question.

Comment: What does "It not working" mean for you?

Comment: learn to use the console in your browser.

Comment: Thank you phil! I looked for this error for a long time. My eyes are getting bad. I just wanted to check to see if the problem was me, or if the platform was not compatible. Also, I know how to use console. I use this platform for sharing purposes. Please, in the future just don't even read my questions. Notice my name, notice my avatar. Your help is unwanted, epascarello. Thank you phil for actually helping me. Lightness I understand, but how would you word this question? I wasn't sure and was ready to move on. I am having a hard time memorizing things, ever since they removed the tumor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to be very careful while typing. You're not calling the right function so nothing happens.

```
function yearsUntilRetirement(name, year) {
  var age = calculateAge(year);
  console.log('hello');
  var retirement = 65 - age;
  if (retirement >= 0) {
    console.log(name + " retires in " + retirement + " years.");
  } else {
    console.log(name + " is already retired.");
  }
}
yearsUntilRetirment("John", 1990);
```

Check the **yearsUntilRetirment("John", 1990);** ! the name doesn't match the function.

Comment: You say "very careful". I say just _looking_ at it would be a good start.

Comment: Yeah that's true.

Comment: ah man I missed that, I looked at it numerous times, I think i need to get glasses or start using bigger font. It's getting harder to see. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you sooo much Volshebnik for your helpful input! So hard to find these days! My eyes must be getting back and without your input I think I would have stared at this for an hour before I facepalmed my brains to the wall :P Thank you again, you are a real blessing, and a kind soul to have helped me with such a simple problem, without going through great extend to make myself, and according to lightness's history, many other people to feel negatively towards their selves. I hope you have a long blessed life Volshebnik to continue to spread good will!

Comment: Ooooh thank you, that's nice !